# How to send Ajax data in controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps, geolocation

I want to recommend the visitors the hotels near by him based on his current location. My problem is how to get not login user latitude and longitude so that i can recommend him nearby hotel.

home.blade.php

```
    <script>
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            console.log(position);
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;

            $.ajax({
                url:'http://localhost:8000/getgeo',
                type:'get',
                data:{latitude:lat,longitude:lng},

//even when  i set some value here data:{latitude:1222323}, i did not get `1222323` in controller


                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert('success');
                }

            });
        });
    }

    </script>
```

I got null in controller
controller:

```
public function geo()
{
    return view('home');

}
public function getCoordinate(Request $request)
{
    return $request->latitude;
}
```

Here i am getting latitude and longitude at console in home.blade.php page .But now got in controller

Route:

```
Route::get('/geo', 'ProductController@geo');

Route::get('/getgeo', 'ProductController@getCoordinate');
```

Comment: have you echo all request data before return function

Comment: You have to use Geo location using their ip address. Form that you can calculate where he is now. You don't need user to login. Eg. Like a google map in mobile. It use to get location using GPS / IP address. Hope you understand

Comment: echo out the values that 'getgeo' is receiving

Comment: i got empty array   [ ]

Answer (score 1):

Change following points:-

```
change ajax url : url:'/getgeo'
And function :-
public function getCoordinate(Request $request)
 {
  if($request->ajax()){
    $data = $request->all();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); // print all data here 
  }

 }  
 Try to change Route:-
 Route::any('/getgeo', 'ProductController@getCoordinate');
```

Comment: i got no thing,only blank page

Comment: try to change route "get to any see" my updated answer

Comment: i have to send automatic ajax request to particular URL without any user click event. I mean if user lands on home page,then send their lat and longitude to particular controller.user do not click any button to send request,there should be automatic process to transfer latitude and longitude to controller.(ie /getgeo url)

Comment: are you sure you are getting latitude and longitude? if you want to run on page loads.... you have to put your script in ready function ... $(document).ready(function){ ...... });